# Convert express Response to http ServerResponse

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, node-http-proxy

I am using both `express` and `http-proxy`. After updating NodeJs types I am getting a type error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'Response<any, Record<string, any>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ServerResponse'.   Types of property 'req' are incompatible.     Type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'IncomingMessage'.       Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'IncomingMessage'.
```

in the following code block:

```
async proxyCall(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<ProxyCallResponse> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.pendingPromises.set(req, {resolve, reject});
    this.proxy.web(req, res);
  });
}
```

so now I am not sure how to convert that [Response](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res) input (coming from express) to the [ServerResponse](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse)  type that http-proxy seems to be expecting.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you show what imports you have, especially for the types? I'm wondering if you need to import `Request` and `Response` from `express`, as it would probably use the ones from `lib.dom.d.ts` otherwise. 

Also, it might be helpful to add some more context to what you mean by "After updating NodeJs types". Presumably you have recently updated something. Was it `@types/node`? If so, from what version and to what version?

Comment: I am importing `Request` and `Response` from `express`. It is `@types/node`: from `15.x` to `16.x` so I imagine there is some breaking change in the typings causing the error..

Comment: `function test(req: Request, res: Response, proxy: Server) {proxy.web(req, res);}` works for me with `@types/node: 16.x`. Which version of `@types/express` are you using?

Comment: `"@types/express": ^4.17.13` and `express: ^4.17.1`

Comment: ooof. the only version of `@types/node` that does not give me issues is 15.6.1 - higher than that (e.g. 15.9.0) I get the error mentioned in the description above.